# Strange behaviour with GetOpenFileName dialog and opencv

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, opencv, dialog

I'm trying to use the open file dialog to allow the user of my program to select an image which will then be processed using opencv.

I have a function in which i open the dialog and try to load the image:

```
Mat load_image()
{

OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
TCHAR szFile[260];       // buffer for file name
HWND hwnd;              // owner window
HANDLE hf;              // file handle

// Initialize OPENFILENAME
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
// Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
// use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = L"All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

// Display the Open dialog box. 
if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)==TRUE) 
    hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile, 
                    GENERIC_READ,
                    0,
                    (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    (HANDLE) NULL);
char filepath[260];
wcstombs(filepath, ofn.lpstrFile, 260);
cout << filepath << endl;
Mat src = imread(filepath);
//imshow("src", src);
return src;
}
```

The code you see here works, opens the dialog box and allows the user to choose a file. The filepath is then converted to string (to be passed into imread). The problem occurs when I try to interact with the image src.

For example, if I uncomment the 'imshow' line, GetOpenFileName will return 0 and the dialog box doesnt even open. This happens more than not, I cant actually access the image because everything I try causes this to happen.

In order for the function to work it is called like this:

```
load_image();
```

But if I try to assign an image ie:

```
img = load_image();
```

the same problem occurs. Help! What could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the previous comment, the `CreateFile` method locks the image file so `cv::imread()` is not able to access/read its content.

Try to avoid using of `CreateFile`, I see no reason of using it in your code, the following code is working well:

```
cv::Mat load_image()
{
    cv::Mat outMat;
    OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
    TCHAR szFile[260];      // buffer for file name

    // Initialize OPENFILENAME
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = L"All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    // Display the Open dialog box. 
    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == TRUE)
    {
        char filepath[260];

        wcstombs(filepath, ofn.lpstrFile, 260);
        cout << filepath << endl;

        outMat = cv::imread(filepath);
    }

    return outMat;
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image = load_image();

    cv::imshow("image", image);
    cv::waitKey(-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are just things I notice in your code...so I don't expect this to work but maybe it will help.

`imread` is probably failing. You opened the file using `CreateFile` and locked it as a result of opening it (No Sharing Attributes. See [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info). `imread` tries to open the file anyways so you don't need to create your own handle! Just use the file path received and call `imread` instead of using `CreateFile`.

```
Mat src;
if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)==TRUE)
{
    // Succeeded in choosing a file
    char filepath[260];
    wcstombs(filepath, ofn.lpstrFile, 260);
    cout << filepath << endl;
    src = imread(filepath);
}
```

Also if you don't have an `hwnd` then you should just set `ofn.hwndOwner=NULL` instead of arbitrarily setting it.

If you so choose to use CreateFile (maybe you wish to open it for manual read access for your own purposes outside of OpenCV), then make sure to call `CloseHandle( HANDLE h )` on the file handle before you open the file again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I try to implement this I get the same issue (the dialog box is not opened, code continues and fails because there is no image)